# Issues Linking CSS File to JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to link a css to my jsp page but I keep getting a 404 page not found error.

href in the homepage.jsp:
  `<link href="../resources/css/welcome.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

```
file structure:
-->webapp
  -->img 
  -->resources
    -->css
      -->welcome.css
  -->WEB-INF
    -->views
      -->homepage.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using Spring MVC:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/welcome.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you hate JSTL, you can use the “page context” variable to get the resources like this :

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/welcome.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: This still didn't work I got this error on the browser when i clicked inspect element on the page. The page displays fine but it can not find the css file.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/resources/css/welcome.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: send me the path of homepage.jsp

Comment: /ProjectOne/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/homepage.jsp

Comment: I mean the web url. When you access it in browser

Comment: In that case just use resources/css/welcome.css , it will pick it up.

Comment: I am getting to the page via request mapping of '/' so when i use that url that you just posted i get a 404.

Comment: Try this url and see if it works http://localhost:8080/ProjectOne/resouces/css/welcome.css

Comment: this also threw a 404

Comment: I am still getting this same error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Do you have any thing like this in your config <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: Thanks mohamedrias, i was just missing that line of code in my config. Thanks for your help, appreciate it :)